# What happened with my text shadows in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, rendering

So I have some simple style [here](http://jsdo.it/oleg.jakushkin/nZo3/fullscreen) previosly Chrome rendered it same way as FF - like this

[image: soft FF 4 rendering]

and all over sudden I look on my document in chrome and see this

[image]

not transparent at all shadows=( What to do with tham - how to fix?

[image]

My [CSS code](http://jsdo.it/oleg.jakushkin/nZo3):

```
body{padding: 5px;background-color: #FFF;font: 100.01% "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif}
h1,h2,p{margin: 0 10px}
h1,h2{font-size: 250%;color: #FFF; text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;}
h2{font-size: 120%;}
div#nifty{ margin: 0 1%;background: #9BD1FA}
b.rtop, b.rbottom{display:block;background: #FFF}
b.rtop b, b.rbottom b{display:block;height: 1px;overflow: hidden; background: #9BD1FA}
b.r1{margin: 0 5px}
b.r2{margin: 0 3px}
b.r3{margin: 0 2px}
b.rtop b.r4, b.rbottom b.r4{margin: 0 1px;height: 2px}
p{color: #000;text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;padding-bottom:0.3em}
input[type="button"], .eButton {width: 150px;padding: 5px 10px;word-wrap: break-word;height: auto;}}
::-moz-selection {   background-color: #fbfdfe;  color: #ff6c24; text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #258ffd;}
::selection {  background-color: #fbfdfe;   color: #fff;   text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #258ffd;}
```

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome 14.0.835.202 & 16.0.903 on OS X 10.7.

Comment: Windows Chrome 14.0.835.202 m brings problem to me,  16.0.903.0 canary  works in a really strange way - first it renders it in a bad way but in a fiew seconds it rerenders it into sutable FF like way.

Comment: Chrome 15.0.874.83 beta-m on XP has the same problem for me. Also, you spelt input as 'inpuut'.

Comment: Windows XP Chrome 14.x & Chrome 2.x renders bad. It must be same kind of rendering bug because changing font-size to 260% fixes the problem.

Comment: This is a known issue: http://crbug.com/23440

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for semi-transparent shadows, you could try using rgba values instead of hex values. So it'd be:

```
h1 { text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.20); }
```

where the first three numbers are the RBG value (Red, Green, Blue) and the fourth number is the opacity (from 0 to 1). So the above example is black at a 20% opacity.

Also, the strange shadow weight seems to be coming from the blur value on the `text-shadow`. When I change it to `1px 1px 0` it gives a more even shadow than `0px 1px 1px`. No idea why.